# Auto Preenchimento de Input em outra aba do navegador via script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Existe algum script que envia o valor do meu input para o input da página que eu abrir ?

Como mostra o exemplo abaixo, eu preciso enviar o valor "12345" para o input da página XYZ assim que eu clicar no link para abri-la, para agilizar a pesquisa pelo código.

#### Meu site:

```
<div>
   <a href="www.paginaxyz.com.br">Consultar</a>
   <input id="CodigoConsulta" type="hidden" value="12345" />
</div>
```

#### Página XYZ:

```
<div>
    <label>Código: </label>
    <input id="Codigo" type="text" value="" <--receber-- "12345" />
    <button id="btnPesquisar" type="button">Pesquisar</button>
</div>
```

Tentei buscar algo em .js e jquery, mas eu não consigo executar os scripts porque eu não tenho o "contexto" da outra página

O script que pensei ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<script>
     var url = www.paginaxyz.com.br;
     $(document, url).ready(function(){
         $("#Codigo").val($("#CodigoConsulta").val());
     });
</script>
```

É possível realizar esse processo ?

Edit: *** A página de destino é de outra empresa, como se eu fosse fazer uma consulta de NFe por chave de acesso, por exemplo ***

Comment: quer fazer no cliente?

Comment: Por que não faz um `post` para a outra página ?

Comment: Já tentou passar como parâmetro GET da pagina XYZ?

Comment: No meu caso, a página de destino não é minha, e não sei a rota/nome do parâmetro que ele espera para a consulta ... tentei passar via get, mas não deu certo ..

Comment: Inspecione a página, veja qual o metodo que o formulario dela utilize. Faça o mesmo no seu sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar o parâmetro por  *query string*, e ler na outra página, uma coisa muito comum e simples:

```
<a href="www.paginaxyz.com.br?codigoConsulta=12345">Consultar</a>
```

**OBS.:** aqui estou só colocando o código direto no link para exemplificar, você pode ler o conteúdo dinamicamente ao clicar no link para pegar o valor atualizado.

Depois, na página XYZ, ler o conteúdo da *query string*, que vem na url.
Existem várias formas de fazer isso, aqui um exemplo copiado do SO: [get query string paramenters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7731778/4730201)

```
$.urlParam = function (name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
                      .exec(window.location.search);
    return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
}
```

Este código criar uma extensão no `jquery`, daí é só usar essa function para recuperar o parâmetro:

```
$("#Codigo").val($.urlParam('codigoConsulta'));
```

Answer (score -3):

Nossa é cada coisa que a gente lê, apesar do cara ter falado que a pagina XYZ, não é dele!!! Fora a solução volumétrica que o povo imagina.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Abrir XYZ</button>

function myFunction() {
  var nw=window.open("https://enderecoDaXYZ");
  nw.onload = function(){
    nw.document.getElementById("Codigo").value= "12345"; //Codigo é o ID do input de XYZ
  }

}
```